# To split the output(s) of a script into two fields and insert that output from a specific row in a csv file

Tags: bash, git, xargs, md5sum

I am trying to split the output of the following code into two fields and insert it from the 3rd row of a csv file

```
#!/bin/bash
cid=`git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H"`
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $cid | xargs -I {} echo '\'{} | xargs -I {} md5sum > final.csv
```

**Current Output** comes as a single line ( need to be separated into fields)

```
title,Path          
              
l34sdg232f00b434532196298ecf8427e /path/to/file              
sg35s3456f00b204e98324998ecsdf3af /path/to/file
```

**Expected Output**

final.csv

```
title,Path                     

l34sdg232f00b434532196298ecf8427e,/path/to/file            
sg35s3456f00b204e98324998ecsdf3af,/path/to/file
```

I am thinking of placing the output of the script in a third file and then reading that file line by line using awk. Not sure if that's the correct way to proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you added some of the intermediate output from before the pipes to the question .... `#!/bin/bash;
cid=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H");
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $cid`

Comment: So .... are you **SURE** that that's what your current output looks like?  If I run that (havinf fixed fromat to format) against a git tree I get something like this:  `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -` repeated on every line. It doesn't look anything like yours.  That said: that **format** of yours is not a CSV, it's fixed-length.

Comment: @tink sorry I couldnt convey the exact meaning through that. I was trying to showcase the csv file as a table, and yes it will show the md5 as well as the path where the file is present as well. Have cross checked that. Have edited the question now

Comment: Well ... your modified `current output` still isn't anywhere near what I see when I run your script.

Comment: May I know what you do see, I get the md5sum value of all the files included  in the  latest commit, displayed line by line

Comment: Sure ... look at my second comment.

Comment: You have a typo: ```cid=`git log -n 1 --pretty=fromat:"%H"` ``` has `fromat` (f RO mat - read only mat?) instead of `format`. This makes me wonder what else you might have retyped (rather than cut-and-pasted) and gotten typos into. I'd suspect you're running into `xargs` implementation differences here with `{}`, perhaps. (I would also recommend using `git rev-parse HEAD` to simplify the hash ID finding.)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overcomplicating things.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cid=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H")
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "$cid" |
xargs md5sum |
sed 's/  /,/' > final.csv
```

This simply replaces the two spaces in the `md5sum` output with a comma.

Because nothing here is Bash-specific, I changed the shebang to `#!/bin/sh`; obviously, still feel free to use Bash if you prefer.

I also switched from the obsolescent `` `backtick` `` syntax to modern `$(command substitution)` syntax.

If you absolutely require the CSV header on top, adding that in the `sed` script should be trivial.  Generally, header lines are more of a nuisance than actually useful, so maybe don't.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of does what you're asking:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cid=$(git log -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H")
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "$cid" | while read -r path
do
        md5sum "${path}"
done | awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s,%s\n", "title", "path";printf "\n"}{printf "%s,%s\n",$1,$2}' > final.csv
```

Comment: Using a separate `printf` for the second newline is ... peculiar. Are you sure you don't prefer simply `printf "%s,%s\n\n", "title", "path"`? Or, assume the empty line is spurious, and really should not be there at all.

Comment: You're quite right @tripleee ...  that was a brainfart.